# Optimize Entity framework Query, avoid lazy-loading

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query that takes a couple of seconds(~2.6s) to run. But i want to reduce that to as little as possible.

I only require reading so I've included the .AsNoTracking() behavior.

I have also tested the query without include statements, but my operations after the get request slowed it down further so i left the includes to optimize my other operations.

**The main goal is to reduce the Database talk, therefor the ToList(),Include statements.**

Code:

```
var obj = _context.MyContextModel.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.CategoryList.Model.Id == 1)
            .Where(x => x.CategoryList.Model.TypeId == 1)
            .Where(x => x.Year.Select(y=>y.Datetime).Any(item => item.Year == 2010))
            .Include(x => x.LinkedMarket).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Year).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CategoryList).AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CategoryList.Model).AsNoTracking();

return obj.AsParallel().ToList();
```

This operation usually returns about 1000-2000 MyContextModel records, not including the "includes"

How can i optimize this further?
Should i load objects to a container class? or another solution?

**Update**

```
_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var obj = _context.MyContextModel.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.CategoryList.Model.Id == 1)
                .Where(x => x.CategoryList.Model.TypeId == 1)
                .Where(x => x.LinkedMarket.FirstOrDefault(mar=>mar.MarketID == marketId) != null)
                .Include(x => x.Year).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.CategoryList).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.CategoryList.Model).AsNoTracking();

return obj.AsParallel().ToList();
```

Basically i've removed where clause which filter the year(I do that later, therefor the include of the year)
I've added a Where clause that specify market from the getgo.

I've removed the Include which contained market.

One big performance thief was the Linked market(i don't know exactly why, something EF didn't like.)

This reduced the query to about a average on 0,4 seconds.
And the whole operation set from 4+ seconds to a stunning 0,7 seconds.

Comment: Did you analyze the generated Query for missing indexes etc. In SSMS?

Comment: something tell me the issue is right there .Where(x => x.Year.Select(y=>y.Datetime).Any(item => item.Year == 2010))

Comment: @ErikEJ . I have no control of the DB, so i cant change anything anyway.

Comment: @Fredou. That only reduced the query 0,2 seconds.

Comment: can you show us the generated sql query? how many row and what the average size of each row? run it under sql server management studio to extract some statistic, dont forget that if this query return 10 meg or 500 meg, you also have the network speed. is this really linq to sql or entity framework? which version?

Comment: @Fredou I will check this tomorrow, im not in my office right now. I will keep you posted. And Yes you are right, this is a EF Question, I've updated the header. Version 6.1.2

Comment: ok, let us know tomorrow, also try without AsParallel() and check version 6.1.3 they have fixed something about 1 to 1 mapping

Comment: you have to much `AsNoTracking()`. Try using `_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`. `Include(x => x.CategoryList.Model)` is useless. Use `Include("CategoryList.Model")`. Otherwise, materialization has a cost.

Comment: @tschmit007, both include should give the same result?

Comment: @Fredou, [afaik](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels) the actual syntax is not correct

Comment: @tschmit007,  yes your right!, i would choose the strongly type/compile time way

Comment: You are using too many includes and the query performance is low because of that. The reasons are described in my answer.

Comment: Do you need *all* columns? You can gain lots by taking a projection.

Comment: @Fredou Did some statistic search in SQL Managemant Studio on my query. The average client bytes received from server is 800000(8Mb). Row count is 876.

Eager loading looks shinier and shiner for every second, that will reduce the whole operations set from 3s to 0.7s.

Comment: that is good, is it possible to see the resulting sql query? i'm curious to see how entity framework write it. with that kind of payload, did you output the query in a debug/immediate windows in visual studio using the log property(DbContext.Database.Log)?, it should also output in millisecond the time spent on sql server

Comment: @Fredou Unfortunately i can't post the full query because security issues regarding column names (And i don't feel like refactor a 300 line long SQL query). Sorry for that.

Comment: i understand, what is the current linq query look like now that it is down to 0.7s or less? and what configuration did you put in (_context.Configuration.??????)

Comment: @Fredou See my OP for a update on the query.

Answer (score 2):

Each include you do will end up with a join being executed in the db.
Suppose your left table is very big 1024 bytes in record size and that you have many details, say 1000 and and that the detail record size is only 100.
This will result in the information for the left table to be repeated 1000 times, this information is going to be put on the wire by the db and EF has to filter out the duplicated to create your left instance.

It can be better to not use include and do an explicit load. Basically executing 2 queries on the same context.

I have an example using this principle below. It can be up to 10 times faster than relying on include. (A db can handle only a limitited number of joins efficiently btw)

```
var adressen = adresRepository
                .Query(r => r.RelatieId == relatieId)
                .Include(i => i.AdresType)
                .Select().ToList();

var adresids = (from a in adressen select a.AdresId).ToList();
            IRepositoryAsync<Comm> commRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<Comm>();

            var comms = commRepository
                .Query(c => adresids.Contains(c.AdresId))
                .Include(i => i.CommType)
                .Select();
```

For the commType and adresType I use include because there is a 1 to 1 relationship, I am avoiding too many joins and thus my multiple queries will be faster than a single one using include. I am not including the Comms in the first query to try and avoid the second query, the point is that 2 queries are faster in this case than a single one.

Bottom line is there is more to consider than just avoiding lazy load, there is also some consideration needed about which includes are needed and which are not. You might need that information, and an include is quick and easy, but an extra query in the same context can be faster.

Comment: Seems to me that EF should be robust enough by now that a person shouldn't have to code multiple queries for data to be returned in a timely manner.  This adds more maintenance headaches.

Comment: @Kix, EF does not replace a humble developer who needs to know the mechanism that are in place and needs to use his common sense. An include is genericly processed as a join, and this has consequences. EF cannot do it any other way because it would have to know the data.

Comment: So as a designer you can use either lazy load, eager load, or explicit load. The designer decides and runs performance tests on his queries.

Comment: I agree, if there is a significant time lapse, then maybe he should think about using a sproc.  This is a bit of an issue with EF because I have faced the same problem.  Was cheaper for me to write a stored procedure and call it through EF.

Comment: Underlying what @PhilipStuyck is saying: EF is, by design, as close to one-to-one with the SQL generated as possible; you're just as likely to write a bad EF query as a bad SQL query. For this reason, good queries in EF - in conjunction with indexes on the DB - are usually as efficient as sprocs, if you try hard enough.

Speaking of which, way more devs need to know the results of IQueryable.ToString() for their EF queries.

Comment: And there is not enough attention to this in the literature either. All first time users, including myself some time ago, are making the same mistakes over and over again.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Thanks for the answer! I understand that multiple queries will give a performance boost. But how do I combine these to queries? Just with simple joins?Unions? What is the most efficient way?

Comment: As in the example I have given. Seperate queries, or more specific separate EF queries.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Ok, So i have constructed my queries to be separated. I did some simple performance tests with "StopWatch". And the separated queries preformed slightly worse than includes. This could be because the many round trips to the sql-server? I'm doing about 7 queries on the same context.(which means 7 trips to the db, over the network).

I've followed some points other mentioned, and googled for a bit, and actually got my query to execute in about 1 second.(will do some more digging, and post results)

Comment: It also depends on how smart you make your queries. For instance in the example above i am creating a list of the addresses, because i want to comms for all those addresses. And then do a query using the contains clause. It really requires some experimenting and measuring query performance, and of course some experience.

Comment: with all the include, entity framework should create a pretty huge query that would do union all between some include and keeping many column null between them. it wont create one query with all inner or left join, order of include is also important. this is used to reduce the number of rows returned to the client. not perfect but at least it work, i had case where one hand written query with all inner join would transfer about 500 meg of data and ~400k rows to the client while the entity query was 30 meg and ~20k rows. same result when in code, processing time was done in the client.