# Entity Framework with Generic Repository and Unit Of work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using Entity Framework with Generic Repository in one of my application. I need to integrate unit of work. I am a bit confused about that what is the best way to add unit of work with Generic Repository Pattern without any effect on performance of application. Can anyone help me to do this.

I have added my Generic repository code and other repository code as below.

Generic Repository:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EntityFrameworkDemo.Entity;
using EntityFrameworkDemo.Models;
using EntityFrameworkDemo.Repository.UnitOfWork;

namespace EntityFrameworkDemo.Repository
{
    public class BaseRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : BaseModel
    {
      internal EFContext db;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        db = new EFContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseRepository"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    public BaseRepository(EFContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Where(t => !t.DeletedOn.HasValue);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the specified identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Get(long? id)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Find(id); ;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the specified identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<T> GetASync(long? id)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the specified current.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The current.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<T> Insert(T current)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Add(current);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }

        return await db.Set<T>().FirstAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the specified current.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The current.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Update(T current)
    {
        db.Entry<T>(current).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the f  ollowing validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the specified identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Delete(long? id)
    {
        var current = await this.GetASync(id);
        if (current != null)
        {
            current.DeletedOn = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry<T>(current).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the specified identifier permanently.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task DeletePermanently(long? id)
    {
        var current = await this.GetASync(id);
        if (current != null)
        {
            db.Set<T>().Remove(current);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finalizes an instance of the <see cref="BaseRepository"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    ~BaseRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged and - optionally - managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Dispose();
                db = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Student Repository :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EntityFrameworkDemo.Models;

namespace EntityFrameworkDemo.Repository
{
    public class StudentRepository : BaseRepository<Student>
    {
    public StudentRepository()
        : base()
    { }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private StudentRepository studentRepo = new StudentRepository();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var test = studentRepo.GetAll();

        return View();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            studentRepo.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, not suitable for SO. If you want to learn EF repository pattern this could be a good read: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Answer (score 4):

You might want to know that Entity Framework context is an implementation of Unit of Work pattern (When you do `context.SaveChanges()` you perform a unit of work). So I am pretty sure, in 90% of cases there is no need to do additional implementation over it, unless you want to abstract your data layer from concrete DataSource/DataAccess. I must say, if you don't need to have this abstraction, you don't need a repository pattern at all.

Anyways, the question is too broad. You should describe your intentions on why you want to use repository pattern in your app.

Comment: I am going to implement a ERP System. I have lots of data in database and I also need transaction when on saving of data.

Comment: .SaveChanges() is always run in a transaction. +1 for not adding a generic repository.

Answer (score 1):

There are pro's and con's on using a generic repository. A repository that has IQueryable in its interface arguably shows the underlying technology which means that replacing this underlying technology becomes a lot harder as IQueryable is not that easy to implement. Hence there are people that say that a generic repository does not provide any abstraction and you might as well use EF right away without a generic repository. (If you can't replace a layer with a different implementation you are too tightly coupled to that implementation).  You'll find that there also people that are in favor of using a generic repository. Repositories can have interfaces and interfaces are mockable and your code will be easy to unit test. To use or not to use a generic repository is for a big part opinion based. Since you are using one I assume you have good reason for needing one

But I don't think you should be writing your own generic repositories/unitofwork from scratch. It is better to base yourself on some implementations that are already freely available and offer good functionality like for instance this one :

https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

It offers what you need and provides for powerful query capabilities and also async and await is supported.

The unit of work itself is not a threat to the performance, because it is just a wrapper around the context of EF which in fact is already a unit of work. The performance issues are situated in the queries that you execute. Those need to be evaluated one by one. And there are a lot of things to consider.

```
- lazy loading
- eager loading
- explicit loading
```

You might want to read my answer to this question about the overly use of includes using EF :

[Optimize Entity framework Query, avoid lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700414/optimize-entity-framework-query-avoid-lazy-loading/28703705#28703705).

Performance is a big topic. There is no easy answer and there is definitely not a one answer that fits all EF performance problems.